# Store encrypted password in xml

Tags: xml, powershell, encryption

I am storing a user name and password in an .xml file with the password encrypted.  When I try to add another username and password, it overwrites the first. How can I append the append the existing file?

```
$username = "user"
$password = "password1" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force | ConvertFrom-SecureString
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username,($password | ConvertTo-SecureString)
$cred | Export-Clixml C:\file.xml
```

I am having difficulty understanding the answer provided. I have tried several different values, what should I be using in place of Node?

```
<Objs Version="1.1.0.1"xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04">
  <Obj RefId="0">
    <TN RefId="0">
      <T>System.Management.Automation.PSCredential</T>
      <T>System.Object</T>
    </TN>
    <ToString>System.Management.Automation.PSCredential</ToString>
    <Props>
      <S N="UserName">Tom</S>
      <SS N="Password">01000000d08c9ddf0115d1118c7a00c04fc297eb01000000fbc3e29e463de248a4643396e70cd6670000000002000000000003660000c0000000100000005f32bf40a436abd21b2855a28a7930f10000000004800000a000000010000000f4d23943a843968368a273547091233b1800000061921de936aa6f7952ef38c53de64f22dcad44e75836a01514000000d50a8b31c7c3a242e82f3c8c1c1105f1431f2a01</SS>
    </Props>
  </Obj>
</Objs>
```

Comment: "When I try to add another", how do you mean?

Comment: Add another username and password  to the file

Answer (score 0):

Your code is overwriting the XML file with every execution.

To modify a specific element within the XML file, you can retrieve it and cast it to an `[xml]` data type, modify its properties using good ol' dot notation, then export the file again.

For example:

```bsh
[xml]$doc = get-content C:\file.xml
$doc.Node = "new value"  # where "Node" is an element within your XML structure
$doc.OuterXml > C:\file.xml
```

In the same vein, you can add new nodes to the XML document as needed.

```bsh
[xml]$doc = "<Nodes><Node>1</Node></Nodes>"
$newNode = $doc.CreateElement("Node")
$newNode.InnerXml = 2
$doc.Nodes.AppendChild($newNode)
# $doc.OuterXml is now <Nodes><Node>1</Node><Node>2</Node></Nodes>
```